# How should you alter user-provided data before it's inserted in DynamoDB GraphQL table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm using AWS Amplify / DynamoDB / AppSync to build a chat app and I want to be able to censor profanity in chat messages.

I don't want to do this client-side because the user can work around that. I don't want to handle it in a Lambda because I want to use gql subscriptions to deliver chat messages in real time (i.e. I want to handle it before it's inserted in the database).

Is the correct way to handle this in the Mutation request resolver? I have a version of that working now but it seems like a long walk around the block to handle this. I also have to remember to update my resolver if I change my auth configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a mutation which modifies chat messages, and then inserts them to DynamoDb. If the logic of message modification is simple, then you can implement the mutation with a [DynamoDb resolver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-resolvers.html). Otherwise, you go with [a direct-lambda resolver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/direct-lambda-reference.html).

Your AppSync subscription should work fine with a direct lambda resolver. It can receive whatever you return from the lambda. For instance: the subscription below can receive both original/altered message contents.

```js
type Mutation {
  sendMessage(input: MessageInput!): SendMessageResult
}

type Subscription: {
  onMessageReceived(receivedUserId: ID!): SendMessageResult
    @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["sendMessage"])
}

type SendMessageResult {
  messageId
  originalMessageContent
  alteredMessageContent
  receivedUserId
  sentUserId
  sentAt
}
```

Comment: Actually, I was trying to implement this and it seems like I can only use Lambda resolvers on response, rather than request.

I'm trying to throw an error if the chat message includes any forbidden words. Using lambdas, I can't prevent invalid messages from being entered into the db.

Comment: It's possibly because clients use another AppSync mutation, or directly inserts into DynamoDb. A resolver is supposed to be a request handler that handles logic and returns a response to clients. Last but not least, you might misconfigure the resolver of the mutation.

Comment: Definitely not going to rule out that I set it up incorrectly. I got it working with the VTL resolver for the `create` mutation. I can't seem to find a way to limit the lambda resolver to only alter data on create.

Comment: I've built a number of direct-lambda resolvers, and never experience such an issue. I cannot help much as I don't know what your lambda looks like. I'd suggest you remove any DynamoDb operation from the lambda, and see if no message is inserted. It's to check if messages are only inserted by the lambda.